# What is the formal definition of a natural instance of non-linearity in consistency strength?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I was inspired to ask this question after watching Joel David Hamkins give a talk about natural instances of non-linearity in consistency strength. Basically, large cardinal axioms seems to be linearly ordered in consistency strength. However, it is known, as a purely formal matter, that the hierarchy of consistency strength is non-linear. The statements used to demonstrate non-linearity are thought of as unnatural. So, that raises the question, what is the formal definition of a natural instance of non-linearity in consistency strength?

Comment: "Natural" is not a formal term, and I'm not aware of anyone seriously proposing a formalization of it.

Comment: There is no widely-accepted formal definition (or even informal definition, really). See the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auVGpgRWDdQ&t=2823s) around the 47:00 mark.

Comment: @NoahSchweber At the Q+A at the end, someone mentions Sacks' question and Martin's conjecture as sort of aspirational analogues from computability theory.

Comment: What's a formal definition of a large cardinal axiom?